# How to deserialise empty array/list?

Tags: json, jackson

I have a property

```
@JsonProperty
private Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

When I try to deserialise by calling objectMapper.readValue(...) everything works fine until the parameters field in the JSON is empty, ie.

```
"parameters":[]
```

I get this exception...

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.HashMap out of START_ARRAY token
```

How do I handle empty list? And no I don't have any control over the JSON coming in.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only get a `HashMap` out of `{}`, not `[]` (you should be able to get an `ArrayList` out of it though).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Chris, your JSON is wrong.

But if you really need to support this, you can (and need to) create a custom deserializer, and register that for declared Map type -- custom deserializer can then accept arrays (at least empty ones, if those are only kinds that can be encountered).